# VS2010: How to see GUI

Tags: visual-studio-2010, forms, visual-c++, user-interface

I need to know how to open the form of a program I am debugging.

I loaded an existing solution into VS2010, I can see the code, but I want to see the GUI part of the project, click on buttons and see what part of the code they take me to, set breakpoints where I feel like.

I don't know how to see the GUI in VS2010, where can I do that?

Also, where would be a good resource to learn the ins and outs of VS2010?

Comment: What language are you developing in?

Comment: the project is using C++

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on how the UI was created, there may or may not be a way to see the UI at design time. Particularly if this is an older Windows UI application, it's likely that the windows are created entirely in code, and there is no design-time UI for you to see.

There is a dialog editor, for dialog windows that are defined in resource (*.rc) files. CTRL-SHIFT-E brings up the Resource Viewer and you can look for things under the Dialog node. It is *possible* that your main window is a dialog-style window, as that's one of the options you get when you create a new MFC-based application.

Otherwise, your only option to see what your UI looks like is to run the program and see. Tracking down which UI elements do which actions in your program will require finding the appropriate event handlers or message handler methods (again, depending on what UI framework, if any, is in use) and setting breakpoints.

Comment: CTRL-SHIFT-E got me exactly to where I needed to be, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The generic answer is:

Hit **F5** to starting Debugging mode. (Or under the Debug menu choose Start Debugging)

But it depends on how your project is setup and what type of project it is if F5 will work that easily for you.

Comment: it was a VC++ 6.0 workspace project, that I converted into a VS2010 project. How can I tell what the project set up is? How can I place a breakpoint on a button? I'm new to this IDE and windows form setup

Comment: What happens when you hit F5?  Does the application start and the GUI appear?  If not, do you have compile errors?  You'd need to fix the compile errors before you can debug breakpoints.    To set a breakpoint open the code file and click in the left column on the line you want to stop on. It should show a red circle icon on the line once you've set the breakpoint.

Comment: I see the GUI when I run it in debug mode (pressing F5). But I'm not yet too familiar with what each button actually does, and I'd like to place breakpoints by those buttons. Perhaps I can search in the code for the text labels of those buttons

Comment: You're close then if you see the GUI in debug mode.   You have to set breakpoints from the code view, so it might take some trial and error to figure where in the code the button click events are.  Set a bunch of break points (one at the top of each function if you have to) and then click the button to see which gets hit. Be aware: The text labels of the buttons will more than likely not be in the same code that gets called when the button is clicked.

Comment: Thanks. I can compile the program and run it in release as well. I just want to know the ins and outs of it :)

Answer (score 1):

What kind of program/language are you using?

With a form, I believe you have to File-->Open-->Project/Solution
Now if its a website, you would open Website. If you tried to open a windows form under a website then you wont see the design.

Typically you would just double click your form name (form1.cs) because then your design view will pop up or hit Shift+F7 or rightclick --> view designer. Then just double click whatever tools you have on your form (like a button) and it will automatically go to the button code.

If its a website, then it would be under website1.aspx while the code sits in website1.aspx.cs

But if none of that helps, here is a good place to learn this stuff

[VisualStudioWalkthroughs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dd441784)

Comment: Whilst that'll work for a C# project, Visual C++ is very different (and the default key bindings are very different too)